# How to verify the boost library I'm using supports C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I would like to check that the Boost library I'm linking against has C++11 support. Is there a function I can run or a define I can verify to be sure of this?

Comment: Do you mean you are worried the library requires C++14/C++17 and it'll break in your environment?

Comment: What version of Boost are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.69.0. I noticed when I compile it does C++11 checks. On Mac I have to pass compile and link flags to specify C++11. So I just wanted to verify that C++11 support was enabled for Boost at runtime.

Comment: @Jason Why do you need and extra runtime check? Either they use it and the DLLs (or .so) link or you should get linker errors if you depend on new functionality being used.

Comment: I thought that there could be optional features that are only enabled when C++11 support is detected, so I would want those extras (especially if they are performance related). When I compile on Mac with ./b2 and don't specifically enable C++11 support I noticed that the config checks for various C++11 features are off. I can continue to check at compile time, I was just thinking that a runtime check could verify this as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `./b2`, you need to compile with C++11 compiler flags:

`$ ./b2 --reconfigure -a cxxflags="-O3 --std=c++11"`